# Specifying Burp Memory

Tags: burp-suite

I am new to Burp Suite. While reading Burp Suite Essentials by Akash Mahajan, I came across one topic on Specifying the maximum memory Burp is allowed to use. It asks readers to allocate 2GB of spare RAM to Burp Suite through writing a command in the terminal. Now I have seen many users to right away open Burpsuite with a double-click and use the testing of applications with not increasing or specifying the max memory as they say that starting Burp Suite by double-clicking on the .jar file, the Java runtime will allocate the maximum memory available to Burp on its own.

1. How much memory usually Java runtime allocates on its own?
2. Do we really need to specify memory?
3. Is specifying memory a task that one needs to do each time while opening Burp Suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Burp uses 50% of your system memory. This default is suitable for most uses and you should not normally need to override it. If you do want to override it (perhaps because you have lots of system memory and less than 50% is sufficient) then you can edit the `vmoptions` file in the Burp directory and override the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default, Burp uses 50% of your system memory.(as said by @PortSwigger)
2. Since Burp Suite will capture hundreds and sometimes thousands of requests and responses of various sizes, it makes sense to allocate memory when we start the program. There is the possibility that Burp Suite might crash if the total memory available is not enough.
3. Depends on you what type of web-app you are testing.